# Navigation drawer is not doing anything on click of the item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I am trying to achieve the following scenario.

An activity containing a view pager having a navigation drawer(opens when swiped left to right) and a search bar that opens when swiped right to left.

**BaseActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dreams.docpad.R;
import com.dreams.docpad.fragments.DashboardFragment;
import com.dreams.docpad.fragments.SearchDoctorsFragment;

public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    /**
     * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
     */
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.concurTypes);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // opens
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                        GravityCompat.START);
                // set up the drawer's list view with items and pclick listener
                mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
                mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


//              if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//                  selectItem(0);
//              }
    }


     //The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer 
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Title is="+getTitle(), 1).show();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }
     @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
                // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
                super.onBackPressed();
            } else {
                // Otherwise, select the previous step.
                mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            }
        }


    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
     * sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new DashboardFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SearchDoctorsFragment();
            default:
                return new DashboardFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }

}
```

**BaseXml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- The main content view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Problem

The click listener on the drawer is not working.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see the toast `Toast.makeText(this, "Title is="+getTitle(), 1).show();`??

Comment: No, i dont see it,thats what makes me feel weird.

Comment: where is your `DrawerListener` ?

Comment: Its there in the code.Check for the class name DrawerItemClickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you give it a try by using below layout :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffe6e1d4"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: it seems same to me . What changed?

Comment: are you keeping inside your relative layout ?

Comment: yes,but removing it from the relativelayout does not change anything.

Comment: This example i have tried it works,but my code is somewhat modified and it has stopped working,may be due to the view pager along with it.

Comment: Oops,you are right,it works, now.Actually i did not clean the project so your solution was not working.Thanks,And can you explain me what actually went wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53877/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-dig)