# My Navigator Drawer is not triggering the Item Select Listener

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm following the [Developer Android Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer) and already search and found questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499696/how-to-add-click-event-to-item-on-navigationview-of-android), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710616/navigation-drawer-is-not-doing-anything-on-click-of-the-item) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667220/navigation-drawer-is-not-closing-while-navigation-item-is-selected).

**I just wanna something that should be simple**, open another activity (or make any action) when a item inside the menu of the navigation drawer is selected.

The menu open in the right behaviour using the FAB.

But when I click on my emulator it close but don't get inside the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener/onNavigationItemSelected, I debugged and the declaration is working, but when I click it won't get inside the listener.

I already tried to implements the listener in the activity and split the method, but didn't work.

Maybe something that can help, in the menu I hint my icons with red, but they still grey.

I already tried to clean, rebuild, open/close Android Studio all this basics that some times Android Studio don't handle.

[image]

**XML Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".screens.intro.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_drawer_header" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/main_user_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/icon_red"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/button_white"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           //My layout/interface

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**XML Menu**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@color/icon_red"
        android:title="@string/home_screen" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer_heal"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_healing_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@color/icon_red"
        android:title="@string/healing" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer_chance"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_warning_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@color/icon_red"
        android:title="@string/chance_of_accident" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer_avoid"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@color/icon_red"
        android:title="@string/avoid_accident" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer_chart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pie_chart_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@color/icon_red"
        android:title="@string/accident_char" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@color/icon_red"
        android:title="@string/about" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer_sign_out"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@color/icon_red"
        android:title="@string/sign_out" />
</group>
</menu>
```

**Code Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    //In Layout
    //navigator drawer
    private DrawerLayout mainDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationView mainNavigationView;
    private FloatingActionButton mainUserMenu;

    @Override
    protected void assignViews() {
        mainDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_drawer_layout);
        mainNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_navigation_view);
        mainUserMenu = findViewById(R.id.main_user_menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepareViews() {
        mainUserMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(Utils.isDoubleClick()) return;
                mainDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        mainNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // set item as selected to persist highlight
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    // close drawer when item is tapped
                    mainDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                    //Do something
                    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the position between NavigationView with FrameLayout.

Your xml activity needs to be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".screens.intro.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/main_user_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/icon_red"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/button_white"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

           //My layout/interface

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_drawer_header" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```